# SugarCRM 6.5 custom module print PDF layout

Tags: sugarcrm

I am a beginner SugarCRM 6.5 developer. I have create custom module details print PDF some confused in controller action and view.detail page. How to create print PDF?

**controller function**

```
protected function action_printinvoice(){

  global $current_user, $db, $region;

  $db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
  $id = $_POST['record'];

  $sql = "select gn.client_name, gn.client_address, gn.client_address_city, gn.client_address_state, gn.client_address_country, gn.client_address_postalcode, gn.id, gn.recipient_name, gn.recipient_address_city, gn.recipient_address_state, gn.recipient_address_country, gn.recipient_address_postalcode, gn.recipient_address, gn.recipient_vat_id, gn.recipient_tax_no, gn.recipient_name, gn.invoice_number as ginvo_client_invoice_id, "
          . " gcstm.* "
          . "from ginvo_client_invoice as gn "
          . " inner join ginvo_client_invoice_cstm as gcstm on gn.id=gcstm.id_c "
          . "where "
          . " gn.deleted=0 and gn.id='".$id."' limit 1 ";


      $result = $db->query($sql);
      $ginv_invoice_ary=array();

      while($row = $db->fetchByAssoc($result) ) {
        $ginv_invoice_ary[]=$row;
      }

      if ($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'non_eu_client_and_freelancer_provider') {
        $region = 'Non EU client and freelancer provider';
      }else if($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'non_eu_client_and_employed_provider'){
        $region = 'Non EU client and employed provider';
      }else if($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'german_client_and_freelancer_provider'){
        $region = 'German client and freelancer provider';
      }else if($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'german_client_and_employed_provider'){
        $region = 'German client and employed provider';
      }else if($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'eu_client_and_freelancer_provider'){
        $region = 'EU client and freelancer provider';
      }else if ($ginv_invoice_ary[0]['region_c'] == 'eu_client_and_employed_provider') {
        $region = 'EU client and employed provider';
      }else {
        $region = '';
      }

      echo json_encode($ginv_invoice_ary);
      //$this->view = 'invoiceprint';
      //$this->view = 'custom/modules/ginvo_client_invoice/metadata/ClientInvoice.php';
      exit;
}
```

**view.detail.php file**

```
<?php
require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');
// require_once('modules/ginvo_client_invoice/view/invoice.php');

class ginvo_client_invoiceViewDetail extends ViewDetail {

function ginvo_client_invoiceViewDetail(){
parent::ViewDetail();
}

function display(){

  echo $ginv_invoice_ary;
//$this->populateQuoteTemplates();
$this->displayPopupHtml();
parent::display();
}

function populateQuoteTemplates(){

  global $app_list_strings, $current_user;

  $inv_id = $this->bean->id;

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ginvo_client_invoice WHERE deleted=0 AND id='$inv_id'";

  $res = $this->bean->db->query($sql);

  $app_list_strings[] = array();

  while($row = $this->bean->db->fetchByAssoc($res)){
    if($row){
      $app_list_strings[$row] = $row;

    }
  }
}

function displayPopupHtml(){

  global $app_list_strings,$app_strings, $mod_strings;

  $templates = array_keys($app_list_strings);

  if($templates){


    echo '
     <script>
    function showPopup(task){
      var record = \''.$this->bean->id.'\';
      var fdata = {\'record\':record};
      var params = jQuery.param(fdata);
      $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        data: fdata,
      //  dataType: "json",
      //  url:"custom/client_invoice.php?"+params,
        //url:"custom/modules/ginvo_client_invoice/ClientInvoice.php?\'+params,
        url:"index.php?module=ginvo_client_invoice&action=printinvoice",
        error:function(resp){},
        success:function(resp){
          $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "custom/clientinvoice.php",
                 data: resp,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (data)
                 {
                   console.log(data);

                 }
             });
        //  location.reload(true);
        }
      });
    // var w = window.open(\'custom/ClientInvoice.php\');
    //
    // $(w).ready(function(){
    //     w.print();
    // });

  }
   </script>';
   }
  else{
    echo '<script>
    function showPopup(task){

    alert(\''.$current_user.'\');
    }
    </script>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a button on detail view.
And extends the SugarPDF class as per below link.
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/SugarPDF/Generating_PDFs/

You can further read at:
https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/29335-how-to-generate-a-quote-pdf-programmatically
https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/19796